# How to add introtext to k2 items in joomla

Tags: joomla, addition, joomla-k2

My question is simple enough i think. In the k2 demo site http://demo.getk2.org/category-blog
there is an introtext in every post which is different from the fulltext of the post. How can i add an introtext like this because i can't see any option similar to that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *Read More*-button in combination with hiding *Introtext* upon viewing the article:

1. Separate the *introtext* from the text the article should contain with a *Read More*.
2. On the right, find *Item view options* and then change *Introtext* to *Hide*.

[image: Separating the text with read more]
[image: Hiding the introtext]